# Building iOS app with Xamarin and Visual Studio 2019 - Error Wrong Version of Xcode installed when it isnt

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying out Xamarin on the Mac. I have an oldish Mac that DID have Xcode 10.1 on it.
I tried to build the iOS app and got the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The Xcode version installed on the Mac (10.1) is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio. This may cause unexpected warnings or errors when building and deploying iOS projects. Please install Xcode '11.3' or visit the documentation to learn more.            0

I upgraded the Mac to Caitlin and upgraded Xcode to 11.3.
I can connect to the Mac and actually can run the iPhone simulator with the app, however, if I run the build, I STILL get the same error, like its not figured out how to update itself?

I have done the 'forget this Mac' and even renamed it on the network in case there was some legacy in a file somewhere.
I have dumped the solution and created a new one from the templates and still get the same error ... hair being torn out...

It might be one of those things that just goes away after a while I don't know. Any ideas?

Thanks.
EDIT * I realised that I wasnt clear. I am running VS2019 on a PC connecting to my Mac.

Comment: Try running `xcode-select` in the terminal to make sure the right command line tools are being used.

Comment: I would recommend uninstalling Visual Studio using an Uninstall script and rerunning the installation again. Setting up Visual studio on MacOS is a lot of grief.

Comment: My appologies, I realise I wasnt clear. This is VS 2019 on the PC connecting to a Mac...

Comment: @BrettJB Hi , have you checked the version of vs for mac whehter be the correct version .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT - I am not using VS for MAC.. its on the PC.. connecting to a Mac..

Comment: @BrettJB I know that . If u own a Mac , you can install VS for mac to check whehter VS can work .